# How to properly test for datatype when deserializing

Tags: c#, object, serialization, binary, deserialization

Im trying to deserialize some objects with type Animal into a list. However i cant seem to figure out how to check that the deserialized object is in fact an animal. The codeexample is what i have. However i cast the object to an animal before i add it to a list of type animal. So i am missing the step in between.

Thanks in advance.

```
public void Load(String fileName)
    {
        if(fileName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
        }
        String path = @"C:" + fileName;
        if (fileName.Contains(@"\"))
        {
            path = fileName;
        }
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
           
            Animals = (List<Animal>)format.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type using `GetType()` and `typeof(T)`:

```
public void Load(String fileName)
{
    if (fileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
    }
    String path = @"C:" + fileName;
    if (fileName.Contains(@"\"))
    {
        path = fileName;
    }
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        BinaryFormatter format = new BinaryFormatter();
        
        object obj = format.Deserialize(fileStream);
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<Animal>))
        {
            List<Animal> Animals = (List<Animal>)format.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, you can mark this as an answer by clicking the check mark button if you found this answer helpful.

Comment: Sadly in the end it does not work, i get an exception: End of stream has been reached before parsing has finished.